# static_cast<Class*> during runtime

Tags: c++, windows

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Topology
{
    int numTargets;
    char a;
};

class Parent {
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    Parent() : name("parent"), age(0) {
        cout << "parent  ctor\n";
    };
    Parent(const Parent& p) {
        name = p.name;
        age = p.age;
        cout << "parent copy ctor\n";
    }
    ~Parent() {};
protected:

};

class Child : public Parent {
private:

public:
    string name;
    int* age; 

    Child() {
        cout << "default Child  ctor\n";
    }
    Child(const Child& c) {
        cout << "child copy ctor\n";
    }
    Child(const Parent* c) {
        cout << "over loaded child copy ctor#1\n";
    }
    Child(const Parent& c) {
        cout << "over loaded child copy ctor#2\n";
    }
    ~Child() {};
protected:
    Topology topology;
};


int main() {

    Parent* p1 = new Parent;
    Child* temp = static_cast<Child*>(p1);
    return 0;
}
```

After static_cast is called the values of the temp object are:

- string name = some random characters
- int* age = 0x00000000
- int topology.numTargets = 0
- char topology.a ='0'

I am investigating the possible issues that arise from static_cast during runtime. Why aren't any constructors getting called? How to these values above get initialized to zero?

Comment: Did you mean `Parent* p1 = new Child`? You're only creating a `Parent` never a `Child`, calling `static_cast` here is ... not good.

Comment: I'm interested in the nitty gritty of why it is not good

Answer (score 2):

> Why aren't any constructors getting called?

Because you just cast a pointer of one type to a pointer of another, no object construction happened.

> How to these values above get initialized to zero?

They are not. If you dereference pointer `temp` you would have Undefined Behaviour, one of many possible outcomes of which you get zero values on those fields.

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast` on a pointer doesn't call any constructors it simply converts the pointer types. As `p1` doesn't point to an object of type `Child`, `static_cast<Child*>(p1)` has undefined behaviour.

If you want to construct a new instance of `Child` then you can use:

```
Child temp = static_cast<Child>(p1);
```

Or more simply:

```
Child temp{p1};
```